# To check whether the table exists or not dynamically

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, information-schema

```
DECLARE @DROP VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TAB VARCHAR(MAX)='Employees'
DECLARE @CREATE VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SELECT VARCHAR(MAX)

--IF OBJECT_ID('DBO.'+@TAB,'U') IS NOT NULL
--BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
              AND TABLE_NAME = @TAB))
BEGIN
    SET @DROP = N'DROP TABLE '+@TAB
    EXEC(@TAB)
END

SET @CREATE= 'CREATE TABLE '+@TAB+
    '(
        ID INT
        ,NAME VARCHAR(50)
        ,PHONE VARCHAR(25)
        ,ADDRESS VARCHAR(100)
    )'

EXEC(@CREATE)
SET @SELECT='SELECT * FROM '+@TAB
EXEC(@SELECT)
```

I get an error, why?

> Msg 2809, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The request for procedure 'Employees' failed because 'Employees' is a table object.

Comment: thats because ur executing table or object not sql script which is located `EXEC(@TAB)` change it to  `EXEC(@DROP)`

Comment: Belated Thanks @YogeshSharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did only one mistake instead  of using EXEC(@TAB) You should use EXEC(@DROP)

```
DECLARE @DROP VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TAB VARCHAR(MAX)='Employees'
DECLARE @CREATE VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SELECT VARCHAR(MAX)
--IF OBJECT_ID('DBO.'+@TAB,'U') IS NOT NULL
--BEGIN
IF 
(EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT 
        1 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
    AND  TABLE_NAME = @TAB
    )
)
BEGIN
    SET @DROP=N'DROP TABLE '+@TAB
    print @DROP
    EXEC(@DROP)
END
SET @CREATE=
    'CREATE TABLE '+@TAB+
    '(
        ID INT
        ,NAME VARCHAR(50)
        ,PHONE VARCHAR(25)
        ,ADDRESS VARCHAR(100)
    )'
EXEC(@CREATE)
SET @SELECT='SELECT * FROM '+@TAB
EXEC(@SELECT)
```

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server 2016 SP1 onwards, objects can `DIE` - `D`rop `I`f `E`xists. So, for your case, you can skip the existence check, and in the dynamic SQL to build only the following T-SQL statement:

```
...
'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + @TAB + ';' + 
'CREATE TABLE ' + @TAB + 
...
```

Literally every object can `DIE`, you can get more details [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/11/03/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016/):

[image]